# Moodle 2.7 - where can I find a list of functions

Tags: php, moodle

I am specifically searching for the get_string function definition, but would like to know if there's a list of all moodle 2.7 functions and where to locate them.

Comment: Looks like a good question for Google.

Comment: No luck there either. Still searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the functions use phpdoc blocks and are usually more up to date than the online documentation - if you are using a decent IDE then it will display the definition - you can also extract all the doc blocks http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/getting-started/your-first-set-of-documentation.html

You can also try the online developer docs for the api's - this is the one for the Strings API

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/String_API#get_string.28.29

phpdoc definition for get_string() in Moodle 2.5 :

```
/**
 * Returns a localized string.
 *
 * Returns the translated string specified by $identifier as
 * for $module.  Uses the same format files as STphp.
 * $a is an object, string or number that can be used
 * within translation strings
 *
 * eg 'hello {$a->firstname} {$a->lastname}'
 * or 'hello {$a}'
 *
 * If you would like to directly echo the localized string use
 * the function {@link print_string()}
 *
 * Example usage of this function involves finding the string you would
 * like a local equivalent of and using its identifier and module information
 * to retrieve it.<br/>
 * If you open moodle/lang/en/moodle.php and look near line 278
 * you will find a string to prompt a user for their word for 'course'
 * <code>
 * $string['course'] = 'Course';
 * </code>
 * So if you want to display the string 'Course'
 * in any language that supports it on your site
 * you just need to use the identifier 'course'
 * <code>
 * $mystring = '<strong>'. get_string('course') .'</strong>';
 * or
 * </code>
 * If the string you want is in another file you'd take a slightly
 * different approach. Looking in moodle/lang/en/calendar.php you find
 * around line 75:
 * <code>
 * $string['typecourse'] = 'Course event';
 * </code>
 * If you want to display the string "Course event" in any language
 * supported you would use the identifier 'typecourse' and the module 'calendar'
 * (because it is in the file calendar.php):
 * <code>
 * $mystring = '<h1>'. get_string('typecourse', 'calendar') .'</h1>';
 * </code>
 *
 * As a last resort, should the identifier fail to map to a string
 * the returned string will be [[ $identifier ]]
 *
 * In Moodle 2.3 there is a new argument to this function $lazyload.
 * Setting $lazyload to true causes get_string to return a lang_string object
 * rather than the string itself. The fetching of the string is then put off until
 * the string object is first used. The object can be used by calling it's out
 * method or by casting the object to a string, either directly e.g.
 *     (string)$stringobject
 * or indirectly by using the string within another string or echoing it out e.g.
 *     echo $stringobject
 *     return "<p>{$stringobject}</p>";
 * It is worth noting that using $lazyload and attempting to use the string as an
 * array key will cause a fatal error as objects cannot be used as array keys.
 * But you should never do that anyway!
 * For more information {@see lang_string}
 *
 * @category string
 * @param string $identifier The key identifier for the localized string
 * @param string $component The module where the key identifier is stored,
 *      usually expressed as the filename in the language pack without the
 *      .php on the end but can also be written as mod/forum or grade/export/xls.
 *      If none is specified then moodle.php is used.
 * @param string|object|array $a An object, string or number that can be used
 *      within translation strings
 * @param bool $lazyload If set to true a string object is returned instead of
 *      the string itself. The string then isn't calculated until it is first used.
 * @return string The localized string.
 */
function get_string($identifier, $component = '', $a = NULL, $lazyload = false) {
```